# Color Highlight On Geo Map

Tags: visualization, tableau-api

I have a dataset where couple of machines are mapped to regions e.g. Emea , APJ , Americas. I have used an external excel file where i have included all the countries which are part of those 3 regions. There are 2 columns in my ext. excel file. Country and Region. Region column i have mapped with my dataset region. By doing this i am able to use geo map representing all 3 regions. Now in my dataset i have some machines and their predicted failure time (future timestamp). How can i highlight the specific region to which the machine belongs to based on the timestamp of failure alert?

Comment: to get started you can post sample data as well to understand your problem better. so that we don't have to cook data all over again !

Comment: MachineName  EventId PredictedTime CriticalEventId  Insertime  Case
XYZ                  10!20!     Timestamp       10!                 Timestamp APJ XYZ                  40!30!     Timestamp       40!                 Timestamp EMEA

Comment: I have tried to create the sample data where we have failure events predicted 30min before. Inserttime is current time and predicted time is 30 min + Currenttime. If someone opens the dashboard at 1:30 PM and if there is an predicted event to occur at 2pm the specific region should blink or change colour or anything else to divert the viewer's attention.